# json deserialize Culture name neutral, PublicKeyToken=null is not supported. Xamarin Forms C#

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Im trying to save a list to preferences in xaamarin forms. I succeed to serialize my list but i have issues in deserializing.

```
public class FlyoutItemPage
    {
        public FlyoutItemPage(string title, Type targetPage)
        { this.TargetPage = targetPage;
            this.Title = title;
        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Type TargetPage { get; set; }  }
}
```

I serialize that list of FlyoutItemPage item when user click button.

```
private async void menuItemFavButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
            var myPage = menuItem.CommandParameter as FlyoutItemPage;

            FlyoutItemPage f = new FlyoutItemPage(myPage.Title, myPage.TargetPage);
            ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage> flyoutItemPages = new ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage>();
            flyoutItemPages.Add(f);
            
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flyoutItemPages);
            Preferences.Set("favorites", json);
        }
```

That is my list come from json and i try to deserialize that.

```
[{"Title":"Depo Aktarım","TargetPage":"İdaServis.View.DepoAktarımPage, İdaServis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}]
```

I deserialize that list on the other page's OnAppearing method.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            try
            {
                var json = Preferences.Get("favorites", "");
                if (json == null) new ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage>();
                Console .WriteLine(json.ToString());
               
                
                **ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage> flyoutItemPages =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage>>(json);**
              
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            
        }
```

But it gives me this error:

```
**System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException:** 'Culture name neutral, PublicKeyToken=null is not supported. Parameter name: name'
```

How can i fix this ?

I want to make a favorite list flyoutpages and set this list to listview inside The Homepage. Then user can go easy that favorite pages.

Comment: serializing UI elements is generally not a great idea.  If you just want a list of Favorite pages, store their name or an ID instead of serializing the entire object

Comment: I stored page id for example 0 then i need to reach this list from other page, right ? I've tried that but list  always comes empty. @Jason

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  If you need help with that problem, [edit] your question to include the relevant details, or post a new question

Answer (score 1):

your class should be

```
public class FlyoutItemPage
{
    public FlyoutItemPage(string Title, string TargetPage)
    {
        this.TargetPage = Type.GetType(TargetPage);
        this.Title = Title;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type TargetPage { get; set; }
}
```

but TargetPage will be always null if you don't have any DLL where the type is defined.

Comment: I fix this problem with a new object without Type. I saved this object to SQLite then i compare these objects and make a new list. This solution is long way but it works for me now.